# Reliable source for ranked courses on post-graduate level in epidemiology?

Tags: reference-request, education

Searching the internet reveals a number of available courses all over the world, but there are no obvious ways to rank them against each other or otherwise approach their quality.

Comment: I'm an epidemiologist, and I know of no such ranking. Your best bet *may* be to try to triangulate based on the faculty there, but even that will be difficult.

Comment: Thank you for replying! Will try to compose an answer if I find the info somewhere.